# Find forces with given their resultant

Tags: trigonometry, physics, resultant

the resultant of two force P and 10 KN is 15KN inclined 30 degree to the 10KN force
find the magnitude and detection of force

i draw my  sketch and try to use cosine rule but i can't find 
please help

[click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B9TE.jpg)

i already see this question 
but i can't understand
[Find one of two forces, given their resultant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005790/find-one-of-two-forces-given-their-resultant)

Comment: I have erased the tag "resultant" which is inappropriate in this context.

Answer (score 2):

$\vec P + 10 \hat i = 15 \cos 30 \hat i + 15 \sin 30 \hat j$,

assuming the $10 KN$ force along the $x$ - axis; and $10KN$ and $P$ to be in the $xy$ plane. We can do that by shifting and rotating the imaginary axes if necessary as in your figure.

So $\vec P$ is ?